# Run a jquery Code after everything has loaded

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I want to jump to hashtag once everything on page loaded. Earlier it was working fine but once I added the flexslider to page, the code is no longer working fine. Here is the code

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if(hash) {
        console.log(hash);  
        var hashlink = hash.replace('#_', '#');
        console.log(hashlink);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hashlink).offset().top - 50
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, 

I have tried that also but as the flexslider is running on jQuery(window).load(function() { so using ready not working.

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: Here is the site currently running: http://goo.gl/2MflEJ

Comment: I downloaded your website in my computer. It works correctly. Try to call all flexslider after your `scripts.js`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                       //your init function
                    }, false);
```

Comment: so how this code will look like:
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if(hash) {
   console.log(hash); 
    var hashlink = hash.replace('#_', '#');
   console.log(hashlink);
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hashlink).offset().top - 50
   }, 200);
  }
 });

Comment: @HimanshuJain Do not bind DOMContentLoaded to window. Just put the code above inside you code and replace function callback with your`s. However, if you would like to use Jquery only here we go: $(document).on('DOMContentLoaded',function(){//your code here}). If you use Jquery version less then 1.8 you have to use bind() instead of on() jquery function. Hope this helps